# Azure AD graph API query for non-empty property

Tags: azure, odata, azure-ad-graph-api

How can I query graph.windows.net for accounts in our Azure AD that do have the email property set? I am asking for the query string, or even better a C# statement using ActiveDirectoryClient.

It doesn't seem possible to use $filter=email neq '' or other similar $filter construct to exclude users that don't have the email property set.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate all the Azure AD users and check if the users have a mail:

```
ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = AuthenticationHelper.GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
List<IUser> users = activeDirectoryClient.Users.ExecuteAsync().Result.CurrentPage.ToList();
var mailUsers = new List<IUser>();

foreach (IUser user in users)
{
 if(user.Mail != null)
 {
    mailUsers.Add(user);
 }
}
```

Please check the sample application at

https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-graphapi-console

Comment: I'm doing that today. I would like to not have to download ALL Azure AD users, and had hoped to filter the irrelevant ones serverside.

Comment: Unfortunately, while using LINQ, Where does not work for filtering for these purposes and it returns error.

Comment: Yeah, this seems ridiculous. I work at a large company with like 100,000 employees, not to mention all the other AD accounts created. It would be impossible to iterate through all of them to filter out the ones that don't have mail set. I thought I'd be clever and use .Contains("@") but apparently the graph api doesn't take Contains either. It's only StartsWith or exact matches.